# RequireJS modules are undefined in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have been pretty much beginner at this part of javascript and I would appreciate any ideas how could be solved this problem.
I use requirejs to define my own modules where I also use backbone.js. 
Let say I have the main module where I initialize my Backbone view which is rendered without any problem. Also, the click event where is calling method createSchemeForm creates the form correctly. The problem raises up in a situation when I call cancel method by click and the modules which are defined for Backbone view (e.g. "unicorn/sla/dom/helper"...) are undefined but when I called method createSchemeForm at the beginning the modules were executed without any problem.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Backbone view

```
define("unicorn/sla/view/scheme", [
   "unicorn/sla/dom/helper",
   "unicorn/soy/utils",
   "unicorn/sla/utils"
], function (DOMHelper, soyUtils, jsUtils) {

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',
        inputData: {},
        btnSaveScheme: 'btn-save-sla-scheme',
        btnCancel: 'btn-cancel-sla-scheme',
        btnCreate: 'btn-create-sla-scheme',
        btnContainer: '#sla-scheme-buttons-container',
        schemeContent: '#sla-scheme-content-section',
        btnSpinner: '.button-spinner',

        events: {
            'click #btn-create-sla-scheme' : "createSchemeForm",
            'click #btn-cancel-sla-scheme' : "cancel"
        },

        initialize: function(){
            console.log("The scheme view is initialized...");
            this.render();
        },

        createSchemeForm: function () {

            this.spin();
            DOMHelper.clearSchemeContent();
            DOMHelper.clearButtonsContainer();
            //Get button
            $btnSave = soyUtils.getButton({isPrimary: 'true', id: this.btnSaveScheme, label: 'Save'});
            $btnCancel = soyUtils.getButton({isPrimary: 'false', id: this.btnCancel, label: 'Cancel'});
            //Append new created buttons
            DOMHelper.addContent(this.btnContainer, AJS.format("{0}{1}", $btnSave, $btnCancel));

            //Call service to get entry data for scheme creation form
            AJS.$.ajax({
                url: AJS.format('{0}={1}',AJS.I18n.getText('rest-url-project-scheme-input-data'), jsUtils.getProjectKey()) ,
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                context: this,
                global: false,
            }).done(function (data) {
                this.inputData = data;
                $slaSchemeForm = soyUtils.getSchemeCreateForm({slaScheme : data, helpText: AJS.I18n.getText("sla-time-target-tooltip-text")});
                DOMHelper.addContent(this.schemeContent, $slaSchemeForm);
                jsUtils.scroll(this.schemeContent, 'slow');
            }).fail(function () {
                jsUtils.callFlag('error', AJS.I18n.getText("message-title-error"), AJS.I18n.getText("sla-error-load-scheme-input-data"));
            }).always(function () {
                this.stopSpin();
            });
        },

        spin: function () {
            AJS.$('.button-spinner').spin();
        },

        stopSpin: function () {
            AJS.$('.button-spinner').spinStop();
        },

        cancel: function () {
            jsUtils.clearButtonsContainer();
            jsUtils.clearSchemeContent();
            $btnCreateScheme = soyUtils.getButton({isPrimary: 'false', id: this.btnCreate, label: 'Create SLA Scheme'});
            DOMHelper.addContent(this.btnContainer, $btnCreateScheme);
            DOMHelper.addContent(this.schemeContent, soyUtils.getSchemesTable(new Array())); // TODO - get current data from server instead of empty array
        }

    });
});
```

Main module where is Backbone view initialize

```
define("unicorn/sla/project/batch", [
   "unicorn/sla/utils",
   "unicorn/sla/data/operations",
   "unicorn/sla/data/validator",
   "unicorn/sla/dom/helper",
   "unicorn/sla/model/confirm/message",
   "unicorn/sla/view/scheme",
   "exports"
], function (jsUtils, operations, validator, DOMHelper, ConfirmMessage, SchemeView, exports) {
    //Load project batch
    exports.onReady = function () {
        $schemeView = new SchemeView();
        $schemeView.render();
    }
});


AJS.$(function () {
    AJS.$(document).ready(function () {
        require("unicorn/sla/project/batch").onReady();
    });
});
```

Comment: Any specific reason as to why you're using BackboneJS?

Comment: The reason is that I define my own views and models

Comment: Can you please provide full error message?

Comment: This is error message from console, when I click on cancel button. TypeError:jsUtils.clearButtonsContainer is not a function

Comment: The error is about `jsUtils`, please include the content of `"unicorn/sla/utils"` in the question.

Comment: But the "unicorn/sla/utils" is include in "define" module of  unicorn/sla/view/scheme. To fire cancel method, first has to be fired createSchemeForm where the modules work correctly, but when should be fired cancel method then starting throw exception about TypeError. The TypeError was also for DOMHelper in cancel method.

Comment: `createSchemeForm` doesn't seem to be using the `clearButtonsContainer` method.  Like already requested please share it's content.